# Why is it wrong to say 覚えていきます?

Tags: grammar, aspect, subsidiary-verbs

if you conjugate a て形動詞 with いく does it mean "I'll do this from here on"?

I understand that it's natural to say 覚えておきます because of the meaning you get when you conjugate with おく (doing in preparation, for the future) but shouldn't it be okay to conjugate with いく, because it's describing an action beginning from now and continuing into the future?

I said 覚えていきます the other day after being told someone's name, but my teacher said it should only be おきます in that situation.

Comment: The only name in the world that you could 覚えて**い**く might be this.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ8Tq5EotaE

Answer (score 2):

覚えていきます has a future tense. It means "I'm going to remember it step by step/gradually from now on." or "I will remember it step by step."

> これから、日本語を覚えていきます。（From now on, I'm going to learn Japanese step by step.)

This is perfectly fine.

> A) 私の名前は、むらかみ　はるき です。
>
> B) 覚えていきます。

覚えていきます has the connotation to remember the thing gradually or step by step. In this context, it might mean that "Okay, I will remember "mura" for today. Tomorrow, I will remember "kami" and "haruki" the day after tomorrow, because I have a bad memory." It doesn't make sense.

> A) あなたは、このクラス40人の担当になります。すべての生徒の名前を覚える必要があります。
>
> B) わかりました。少しずつでも覚えていきます。

This is perfect.

> A) 私の名前は、むらかみ　はるき です。
>
> B) 覚えておきます。(I'll remember your name for your sake. although I don't want to.　or Okay, I remember it just in case.)

This is grammatically correct, but it would be very offensive. The person B is a very socially-high-ranked person. And the person B thinks that A is inferior to B.